# Using DIV in php script

Tags: php

Here is my question. Simple question and I cannot seem to get it. I have 3 radio buttons. Each one that is picked displays what content I have in page. Yet when I pick Green the div cannot display correctly. I think it is the `"` throwing it off. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 $options[] = array( "name" => __('Radio Buttons','framework_localize'),
        "desc" => __('These are radio buttons.','framework_localize'),
        "options" => array(
            '<h1>Testing</h1>' => 'Red',
            '<div class="column5">' => 'Green',
            'Blue Radio' => 'Blue'
            ));
```

Comment: What does `column5` do? Also, it would be helpful if you created a fiddle from the HTML that is rendered on the page

Comment: its puts 5 columns on the page

Comment: is the `div` closed?